# How does rails controller parse JSON and auto-nest the parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a file "5.json" that looks like:

```
 {"id": "5","name": "test"}.
```

There is no root node. When I run curl:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data "@5.json" http://localhost:3000/todos/5
```

rails automagically provides these params to the controller:

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"5", "name"=>"test"}, "todo"=>{"name"=>"test"}}
```

Can anyone point me to why/how rails is automatically nesting the json under 'todo' in parameters? I like it - just wish I knew the why/how. Looked at action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser and didn't see anything in there.

Rails 3.2.14

routes entry just looks like

```
 resources :todos
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, just found it: action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb described here:
http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html

and I do indeed have a wrap_parameters.rb configured for :json.

Comment: now question is, how does it know which params to wrap? Can I add some param except for the  standard Model properties?

Comment: Found a question about that with non-ideal but meaningful answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286962/how-to-add-extra-virtual-attribute-to-wrap-parameters