# How to add extra virtual attribute to wrap_parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with some virtual attributes, and they are included in my form and gets submitted to the controller, but I cannot get the virtual attributes (SKU) to wrap inside the model hash

```
 {"name"=>"Productname", "description"=>"Description", "sku"=>"ak0001", "product"=>{"name"=>"Productname", "description"=>"Description"}}
```

I can use the wrap_parameters to overwrite it, but I would have to add all attributes (virtual and non-virtual attributes) to the array, can't I just add the virtual attributes to the existing wrap parameter?

```
wrap_parameters Product, :include => [:sku, :name, ..etc...]
```

Comment: I have this exact question... shame there's no answer :(

Good luck

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, I haven't found a great solution, but I have found one that seems slightly better.  By default rails will try to determine the related model and call wrap_parameters with that model, so in your case

```
wrap_parameters Product
```

Which is exactly the same as

```
wrap_parameters Product, include: Product.attribute_names
```

So if you want to add a virtual attribute you can just do

```
wrap_parameters Product, include: Product.attribute_names + [:sku]
```

Answer (score 1):

Still haven't found any good solutions. For now instead of using wrap_parameters, I am overwriting the permitted_params

```
    def permitted_params
      {
        :product => params.require(:product).merge(
        {
          sku: params[:sku], 
        }
        ).permit(*permitted_product_attributes)
      }
    end
```